# How to allocate amount using Oracle SQL in ascending order

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm  not able to build Oracle SQL to Allocate budget amounts to require to projects. I have Budget table and Project tables. I want load into Allocation table as given below.

Budget table:

| Category | Budget_Amt |
| --- | --- |
| Cat_A | 110 |
| Cat_B | 20 |
| Cat_C | 30 |
| Cat_D | 80 |
| Cat_E | 100 |

Project table:

| Project | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| Proj_1 | 80 |
| Proj_2 | 60 |
| Proj_3 | 50 |
| Proj_4 | 20 |
| Proj_5 | 140 |
| Proj_6 | 30 |

allocate budget to project in ascending order

Allocation table:

| Category | Project | Budget | Cost | Allocation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cat_A | Proj_1 | 110 | 80 | 80 |
| Cat_A | Proj_2 | 110 | 60 | 30 |
| Cat_B | Proj_2 | 20 | 60 | 20 |
| Cat_C | Proj_2 | 30 | 60 | 10 |
| Cat_C | Proj_3 | 30 | 50 | 20 |
| Cat_D | Proj_3 | 80 | 50 | 30 |
| Cat_D | Proj_4 | 80 | 20 | 20 |
| Cat_D | Proj_5 | 80 | 140 | 30 |
| Cat_E | Proj_5 | 100 | 140 | 100 |

Comment: You say "allocate in **ascending order**" Ascending order of WHAT? It appears that the "order" is by alphabetical order of the category and project *names*, or perhaps of something else not shown in your inputs; the "matching" of categories and projects in your desired output is clearly not ordered in any way by "amount" in either table. Separately from that: What is your Oracle version? Different solutions (usually better ones) are available in newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a tricky problem.  The key idea is to calculate the running budget and running costs -- and then treat this as an overlap between the running amounts.

The following takes this approach:

```
select p.*, b.*,
       least(running_budget_amt + budget_amt, running_cost + cost) - greatest(running_budget_amt, running_cost) as amt
from (select b.*, sum(budget_amt) over (order by category) - budget_amt as running_budget_amt
      from budget b
     ) b join
     (select p.*, sum(cost) over (order by project) - cost as running_cost
      from project p
     ) p
     on p.running_cost < running_budget_amt + budget_amt and
        p.running_cost + cost > running_budget_amt
order by p.project, b.category;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6c3843087701f09d92280b2514c84af8) is a db<>fiddle.